# How to reference renamed MSI in bootstrapper?

Tags: wix, burn

In my `WIX` setup (version 3.10) project I rename the MSI using the script below. Then I reference this setup project in my bootstrapper project:

```
<MsiPackage Id="MyMSI" SourceFile="$(var.Setup.TargetPath)" Vital="yes" />
```

This results in a compilation error. `Light.exe` cannot find the output file:

```
error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file 'X:\Setup\bin\x64\Release\Setup.msi'.
```

Here's the script that successfully renames the output MSI before it is compiled:

```
<!-- Setup.wixproj -->
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\MyApp.exe">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersion" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(OutputName).$(Platform).Setup.%(AssemblyVersion.Version)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetName" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetFileName" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetPath" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DefineConstants>BuildVersion=%(AssemblyVersion.Version)</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

Compiling under Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I've got the same problem.

Comment: Don't rename it. Renaming an msi is not a supported scenario in the first place.